# Type Error when using Typescript with React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, typescript1.8

I am trying to use react-redux with typescript and I'm getting a type error when I try to inject props using connect() and mapStateToProps.

My component looks like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        counter: state.counter
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        incr: () => {
            dispatch({type: 'INCR', by: 2});
        },
        decr: () => {
            dispatch({type: 'INCR', by: -1});
        }
    };
}




export default class Counter extends React.Component<HelloProps, any> {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
              <p>
                  <label>Counter: </label>
                  <b>#{this.props.counter}</b>
              </p>
              <button onClick={e => this.props.incr() }>INCREMENT</button>
              <span style={{ padding: "0 5px" }}/>
              <button onClick={e => this.props.decr() }>DECREMENT</button>
        );
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
```

The store looks like this

```
let store = createStore(
    (state:HelloState, action:HelloAction) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'INCR':
                return {counter: state.counter + action.by};
            default:
                return state;
        }
    },
```

Finally, I have defined my types to be:

```
interface HelloProps {
    counter?: number;
    incr?: () => any;
    decr?: () => any;
}

interface HelloState { 
    counter:number;
}

interface HelloAction { 
    type:string, 
    by:number;
}
```

When I try and compile the code I get the following error:

```
(39,61): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Counter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<{ counter: any; } & { incr: () => void; decr: () => void; }> | StatelessComponent<...'.
  Type 'typeof Counter' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{ counter: any; } & { incr: () => void; decr: () => void; }>'.
    Type 'typeof Counter' provides no match for the signature '(props?: { counter: any; } & { incr: () => void; decr: () => void; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'
```

Interestingly the code still works even though it throws the type error. Also, changing the component's prop interface to any also solves the issue. It seems like the type system doesn't understand that the two objects are merged by the two mapped functions.

Comment: You are exporting the Counter Component twice, maybe that can also be an issue here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer in the second to last post on this Github [issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/6237). Without the type parameter on both the `mapStateToProps` and/or `mapDispatchToProps` or on `connect` it will produce an intersection of the return types of the two map functions.

Comment: did you found out anything more (explanation) about this? I noticed that you didn't receive any answer on your question on the github issue. Are you using return types for the mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps (for which you probably had to made the members of the interface optional like you suggested)? That is how I am currently applying it to be able to run.

Comment: Yeah I specified the return types on mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps. The interface members do have to be optional no matter what otherwise it will fail where the component is called. I'm not a huge fan of how TS works with Redux and react-redux's connect method but I can't think of a good way around that right now.

Answer (score 40):

To preserve type safety you can divide your props in parts, one responsible for normal props and one for dispatchers:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {connect}  from 'react-redux';

interface StateProps {
    textPros: string,
    optionalText?: string,

}
interface DispatchProps {
    onClick1: Function,

}

class MyComp extends React.Component<StateProps & DispatchProps , any> {
    render() {
         return (<div onClick={this.props.onClick1}>{this.props.textPros}</div>);
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProp? :any):StateProps  => ({
    textPros: "example text",
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any):DispatchProps => ({
    onClick1: () => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CLICK_ACTION'});
    }
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComp);
```

For those who search for quick workaround: just add 'as any' to base component.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComp as any);
```

Comment: In my case, I didn't have any values for `mapDispatchToProps`, so explicitly passing `null` or `undefined` instead of leaving off the value seemed to make the error go away: `export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(MyComponent);`

Comment: as. as? as! \\(^o^)/

Comment: This specifically fails as you need to type-parameterize connect:

Even then, there seem to be deeper issues with connect.

Comment: What's the point to use TypeScript and then put `any` here and there? Bad example.