# Argument of type 'typeof -' is not assignable to parameter of type ComponentClass error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am setting up TypeScript for a React/Redux project.

Following the standard Redux pattern, I have a Component Foo and a ComponentContainer FooContainer.

```
// Foo Component file
interface FooProps {
  fooProp: string <-- I think props have something to do with the issue
}     

class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps, {}> {
  ...
}

// in FooContainer file
...
const FooContainer = 
   connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Foo <--)
   // Foo throws TypeScript error 
   // Argument of type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable
   // to parameter of type 'ComponentClass
```

Comment: what do your mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps look like? what are their types?

Comment: Neither have types which might be the problem...

Comment: setting the connect type to <{},{},{}> made the error go away but doesn't really seem to be the correct approach. Hopefully this is a clue to set me on the path to figuring out the issue.

Comment: Make your actions of type any, and your state in those two functions and see what happens. Don't change the connect functions type

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010193/type-error-when-using-typescript-with-react-redux